# Capture logged in user sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How do I achieve this: getting who just logged in to a sharepoint site. The SPF is using active directory/windows based.

I am trying to set a value in a list of users as soon as the user logged in? for all users.

thank you!

Comment: What are you options? You tagged the post with sharepoint-designer. Are you able and willing to deploy code? If no server side code... is client side javascript an option? out of the boy this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/b114c3e4-4f21-4d21-97f7-2ed698e41873

You would need to create a new login page.